# Error: Plugin/Presets are not allowed to export objects, only functions. After update to react native 0.57

Tags: react-native, babeljs

I am trying to upgrade my app from react native 0.56 to 0.57.3, but I'm getting the following issue when my app is loading:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /Users/otaviogaiao/Projetos/citsmart/citsmart-itsm-mobile-field-service/node_modules/babel-preset-react-native/index.js
    at createDescriptor (/Users/otaviogaiao/Projetos/citsmart/citsmart-itsm-mobile-field-service/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:178:11)
    at items.map (/Users/otaviogaiao/Projetos/citsmart/citsmart-itsm-mobile-field-service/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (/Users/otaviogaiao/Projetos/citsmart/citsmart-itsm-mobile-field-service/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (/Users/otaviogaiao/Projetos/citsmart/citsmart-itsm-mobile-field-service/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:101:10)
    at presets (/Users/otaviogaiao/Projetos/citsmart/citsmart-itsm-mobile-field-service/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:47:19)
    at mergeChainOpts (/Users/otaviogaiao/Projetos/citsmart/citsmart-itsm-mobile-field-service/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:315:26)
    at /Users/otaviogaiao/Projetos/citsmart/citsmart-itsm-mobile-field-service/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:278:7
    at mergeExtendsChain (/Users/otaviogaiao/Projetos/citsmart/citsmart-itsm-mobile-field-service/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:294:21)
```

I have tried deleting node_modules, cleaning the build folder, etc.

My package.json file is:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "date-fns": "^1.29.0",
    "lodash.intersection": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash.isempty": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash.pick": "^4.4.0",
    "normalizr": "^3.2.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "16.5",
    "react-native": "0.57.3",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-code-push": "^5.4.2",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.12",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.10",
    "react-native-map-link": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-maps": "git+https://github.com/otaviogaiao/react-native-maps#master",
    "react-native-maps-super-cluster": "git+https://github.com/otaviogaiao/react-native-maps-super-cluster.git#1.4.2",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^6.5.0",
    "react-native-nested-scroll-view": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.1.6",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "3.0.9",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^3.3.5",
    "react-native-text-input-mask": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "2.0.4",
    "react-navigation-redux-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
    "remove-accents": "^0.4.2",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.13",
    "url": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "22.4.4",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.8.2",
    "jest": "22.4.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.45.0",
    "prettier": "1.12.1",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5"
  },
```

and this is my .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react-native",
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source"
      ]
    }
  },
  "retainLines": true
}
```

I looked around for answers, but couldn't find anything that helped me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to use `react-native` anymore, as long you're using the metro one, I don't know if that will fix your issue, but it worth trying. Also I don't why you're using plugin-transform-react-jsx-source, try to build without it

Comment: @TareqEl-Masri Removing React Native worked!! Thanks!